# jQuery drag and drop expands

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

What I want to do is drag the cube over the box.
The box expands and the cube can be placed on one of the 3 'timelines'.

my html:

```
<div class="drag"></div>
<div class="AddRoom One">
    <div class="timeLine">
        <div id="t1"></div>
        <div id="t2"></div>
        <div id="t3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="AddRoom Two">
    <div class="timeLine">
        <div id="t1"></div>
        <div id="t2"></div>
        <div id="t3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: '#t3, #t2, #t1',
        snapMode: 'inner'
    });
    $(".timeLine").droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('height', "66px");
            $(".timeLine #t1").droppable({});
            $(".timeLine #t2").droppable({});
            $(".timeLine #t3").droppable({});
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('height', "24px");
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('height', "24px");
        }
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H7XV9/

As you can see it is possible to drop it on t1, t2 and t3.But I only want t2 and t3 to be droppable when the timeline is expanded!

Comment: If timeline is expanded and you have dropped it does it need to stay extended?

Comment: No it does not need to be extendend. As i tried to achieve in the drop: it collapses again.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
overflow:hidden
```

on t2 and t3

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYssU/1/)

Also, I converted them to a `class` rather than `id`. It's illegal to have multiple IDs in the real world, it should be illegal in HTML too.

### Update from OPs comments

#### Markup

To each `t#` class I added a `drop` class

```
<div class="drag"></div>
<div class="AddRoom One">
    <div class="timeLine">
        <div class="drop t1"></div>
        <div class="drop t2"></div>
        <div class="drop t3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="AddRoom Two">
    <div class="timeLine">
        <div class="drop t1"></div>
        <div class="drop t2"></div>
        <div class="drop t3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: '.t3, .t2, .t1',
        snapMode: 'inner'
    });
    $(".drop").droppable({ // Just assign the event to the drop class now
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().css('height', "66px");
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().css('height', "24px");
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().css('height', "24px");
        }
    });
});
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/LYssU/10/)

Comment: What I would like to achieve is that, when timeline expands t2 and t3 will be available to drop on. When timeline is collapsed t2 and t3 will be disabled to drop on. With overflow: hidden they are disabled all the time.

Comment: @BasvdPol The JS has to be converted to classes too. Check the new JSFiddle

Comment: when the box is on t1 and you try to drag it on to t2 or t3. Timeline still collapses. Using classes is a good idea but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @BasvdPol, it's closer than before.